# Restrict mouse to primary monitor when a specific program is running

Tags: mouse

I have a dual monitor setup and I'm playing a Roblox game. Even when Roblox is in fullscreen mode, my mouse isn't restricted to the primary monitor so it shoots out to the 2nd monitor.
What python libraries can I use to restrict my mouse to the Roblox window when it's Roblox is running?

Answer (score 0):

so after a bit more research, I was able to make this:

```
import mouse
import pyautogui as pag

while True:
    posX, posY = pag.position()
    if posX < 0:
        mouse.move(0, posY)
    if posY <= 32:
        mouse.move(posX, 32)
    if posY >= 1025:
        mouse.move(posX, 1025)
```

But I wonder if there's a more efficient way of doing this?